# my data from different adapters is stored in a single model how do i store them in different models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember Data: cli 4.12

I have created 2 modles **user** and **repo** and 2 adapters with same name user and repo also 2 serializers with same names.

I am calling store.findAll 2 times in a single route's model hook for both repo and user and returning the data.

when I check ember data in ember inspector I only see one model name ie user with repo data appended at bottom for same attribute names and undefined for others.

I want to know how to set models for different calls.

I dont have any code available to paste right now ask me if you dont understand this query, thank you.

i tried asking chatGPT turns out its not great for ember framework and keeps givng me weired codes probably of older cli and new ones mixed

Comment: How do your models look like? What adapters and serializers are you using? How does your response look like?